# How to query data in cells based off of userform combo box selection and copy data into userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is a simple question but I'm still very new to this and trying to learn.  Y'all have already helped me immensely.

I have a sheet within a workbook that stores the data options I enter into userform textboxes.  The idea is that I enter a name into a combo box on the userform and click a "Save" button which copies the text from the various text boxes onto a hidden spreadsheet that I can "load" later with another button.

My code to save the textbox data works fine, however I'm having issues getting the combo box to reference the dynamic range (in a column) I created.  Also I am not sure how to write the code to copy the data from the row that the combo box selection is in.

Example:

Name        Datafield1    Datafield2    Datafield3
Preset1       Purple         10000         Banana

I want my combo box to populate with the dynamic range under name and automaticall copy "purple", "10000, "Banana" into textbox 1, 2, and 5

I have gotten combo boxes to populate with static ranges before but I have never tried to get userform testboxes to populate based upon what I select in the combo box

For the dynamic range piece I have a couple of lines of code that make the sheet with the range active and sets the rowsource for the combo box

I'm not sure where to start with referencing the other cells in the combo box selection row

So far I'm not getting any error messages because I can't figure out how to get the dynamic range to work or how to get the textboxes to populate. Thanks in advance for the help, you guys are awesome.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize() 

'Empty preset name combo box 

presetname.value = ""

With Sheet6
   Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlUp)).name = "presetnamerange"
End With 
   Me.presetname.rowsource = "presetnamerange"

End Sub



'I have a sub for the combo box but I'm not sure what to put in it

Sub presetname_change()

With Sheet6

'????

End With 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where exactly you want to store the textbox values so I just store them in the hidden sheet in cells A1, B1, C1. This can be easily changed to fit your needs.

This is how i would do it:

The `Userform_Initialize()` sub is located in a module and is called by clicking a button located in the sheet where the data is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Userform_Initialize()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sourceRng As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of the Sheet") 'where the data is

With sht
    Set sourceRng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = sourceRng.Value
Load UserForm1
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

When the button is pressed, the userform appears and the combobox has already been initialized.

The `ComboBox1_Change()` sub which is located in the userform itself, is triggered when the combobox's value is changed. When this happens, the textboxes are automatically loaded with the corresponding values.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim dataRng As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of the Sheet") 'where the data is

With sht
    Set dataRng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, dataRng, 2)
TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, dataRng, 3)
TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, dataRng, 4)

End Sub
```

[image]

Finally, clicking the save button, will write the value of the textboxes to the hidden worksheet. The `SaveButton_Click()` sub is also located in the userform.

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim dataRng As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of hidden Sheet") 'where the data should be stored
With sht
    .Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value
    .Range("B1").Value = TextBox2.Value
    .Range("C1").Value = TextBox3.Value
End With
Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely helps.  Everything works except I can't get the combo box to populate with the dataRng values.  I'm sure I am doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.  I'd upload the code but it is on a stand-alone system.  I'll keep going through to see if I fat-fingered something.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ARCHER1919 I am not sure I understand the problem. Keep in mind that the combobox in the code above is populated with `sourceRng` not `dataRng`. So basically when the combobox is expanded, you will see `Preset1`, `Preset2` etc.  as options of the drop down menu. Isn't that what you need? `dataRng` is only used as a variable to hold the range where your data is located so that the `VLookUp` can be performed.

Comment: My apologies.  The issue I was having was that the combo box wasn't populating at all.  It was a typo on  my part.  Looks like I needed better attention to detail.  Thanks again for helping me out with this!